# Hibernate soft deletion with cascade sets FK to NULL

Tags: hibernate, cascade, soft-delete

I am trying to implement soft-deletion using Hibernate annotation with following entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
  ...
@Column(name = "DELETED")
protected boolean deleted = false;
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TARGET")
@Where(clause = "deleted = '0'")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE target SET deleted = '1'")
public class Target extends AbstractEntity {
  ...
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "TARGET_ID")
private Set<Recording> recordings;
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "RECORDING")
@Where(clause = "deleted = '0'")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE recording SET deleted = '1'")
public class Recording extends AbstractEntity {
  ...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TARGET_ID")
private Target target;
  ...
}
```

The deletion itself is a call to EntityManager:

```
entityManager.remove(target);
```

After this call both Target and all of its Recordings have deleted flag set to TRUE as expected.
BUT the Recordings also have the TARGET_ID column set to NULL which is quite unfortunate since the relation is lost. This is NOT what I would expect and restoring the state is impossible.
I would expect the TARGET_ID still hold reference to Target.

Am I doing something wrong? Or do I have to call delete for each Recording manually without using cascades?

Done with Spring Data JPA 1.11.4, Hibernate 5.0.12 and JPA2.1.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0):

Your @OneToMany relation from Target to Recordings is set incoretly. Try:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="target", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Recording> recordings;
```

Comment: The relation is just fine. Using this way you can manage the relation from both sides without any additional effort.